# Parent remove not working

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to run a parent remove after an post request but it doesn't seem to be working.

Any idea why? Here is my code. Ideally, I'd like it to remove the element that $currentId finds.

```
$('#chat').on('click', '.delete', function () {
    var $currentId = $(this).parent().attr('id');
    $.post("assets/delete.php",{ id: $currentId },function(data)
        {
        $(this).parent().remove();
        }
    );
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You changed scope. Try this:

```
$('#chat').on('click', '.delete', function () {
    var parent = $(this).parent();
    var $currentId = parent.attr('id');
    $.post("assets/delete.php",{ id: $currentId },function(data)
        {
        parent.remove();
        }
    );
});
```

Comment: This answer is better than the others, because it's always best to use less `$(...)` calls (I've worked on projects where simple difference between your, and Jack's code means 50% performance).  Nice work!

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because the `$(this)` inside `$.post` refer to `$.post` and not to `$('#chat')`.

try this:

```
$('#chat').on('click', '.delete', function () {
    var $currentId = $(this).parent().attr('id');
    var that = $(this); 
    $.post("assets/delete.php",{ id: $currentId },function(data)
        {
        that.parent().remove();
        }
    );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

After 'post' finishes, your 'this' does not refer to the element you think. You have to use
$('#chat').parent().remove()

Edit: Jacks answer is even better, as it does not need to find element with ID = chat. Assigning it to a temporary variable (in his example, that) is a faster option.